# Search and Replace email ids present in database using reg exp

Tags: php, mysql, regex, preg-replace, replace

I want to search and replace all the email ids present in database with email ids appended with extra text.

For example:

```
Before: someone@example.com
After:  someone@examplexyz.com

Before: greatperson@yahoo.co.in
After:  greatperson@yahooxyz.co.in

Before: contactus@boxbe.net
After:  contactus@boxbexyz.net
```

Here the term "xyz" is appended to all the domains.

Basically I want to change the email ids in such a way that the email ids won't be invalid, rather the domain should not work as invalid when a mail is sent. I need this, to use the live DB but don't want emails be sent to the real users. My current code setup is LAMP(Linux, Apache, Mysql, Php).

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: do you want to update them in your database ? or just in the PHP scripts ?

Comment: Why dont you just harcode the email field if your purpose is not sending the mail to? Or just commenting the line which sends the mail...

Comment: I want to update the emails in the database. I can hard code but I want keep the mail functionality but not to the real users. After search and replace I want will change one or two emails to right one and keep working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to change them in your php script using regex you can try

```
<?php
    $email = "aburomaissae@domaine.com";
    echo "Before: ".$email ."<br>"; 
    $email = preg_replace("/@([a-zA-Z1-9]+)(\.[a-zA-Z]+)/","@$1xyz$2",$email);
    echo "After: ".$email ."<br>";
```

this script will print

> Before: aburomaissae@domaine.com
>
> After: aburomaissae@domainexyz.com

Comment: How can I search and replace in database ?

Comment: I saw your comment left for `Ken Clark` I guess for you case if preferable to change them in the code just before sending the email using regex as show in my post

Comment: Thanks. I will apply this.

Comment: welcome, I am happy I could help, if this is useful for you, please do not forget to accept :)

Answer (score 0):

In MySql:

```
Update TableName Set Email=Replace(Email,'@','@xyz')
```

Comment: In the database there are lots of columns which contains email ids. In any way I have to search the whole database for email patterns and replace those.